# Duplicate Logging from Waitress with Custom Logger

Tags: python, flask, logging, python-logging, waitress

I have the following code, but am still seeing duplicate messages from waitress. I'm not sure of the reason why if I've cleared out all the handlers. Does anyone have any thoughts? I instantiate and use my EventLogger wrapper in other places in the code.

```
from typing import (
    Any,
    Tuple,
)
import logging
import traceback


class bcolors:
    """Colors class for logging"""

    HEADER = "\033[95m"
    OKBLUE = "\033[94m"
    OKGREEN = "\033[92m"
    WARNING = "\033[93m"
    FAIL = "\033[91m"
    ENDC = "\033[0m"


class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Custom formatter for our logging module"""

    # format = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s] - %(message)s (%(true_filename)s:%(true_lineno)d)"
    new_format = "%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s] - %(message)s "

    FORMATS = {
        logging.DEBUG: bcolors.OKGREEN + new_format + bcolors.ENDC,
        logging.INFO: bcolors.OKBLUE + new_format + bcolors.ENDC,
        logging.WARNING: bcolors.WARNING + new_format + bcolors.ENDC,
        logging.ERROR: bcolors.FAIL + new_format + bcolors.ENDC,
        logging.CRITICAL: bcolors.FAIL + new_format + bcolors.ENDC,
    }

    def format(self, record: Any) -> str:  # pylint: disable=function-redefined
        log_fmt = self.FORMATS.get(record.levelno)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(log_fmt)
        return formatter.format(record)


flask_log = logging.getLogger("werkzeug")
flask_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
flask_log.disabled = True
flask_log.propagate = False

waitress_log = logging.getLogger("waitress")
waitress_log.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
waitress_log.disabled = True
waitress_log.propagate = False

logger = logging.getLogger("my_application")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch.setFormatter(CustomFormatter())
logger.handlers = []
logger.addHandler(ch)


class EventLogger:
    """Defacto logger for work"""

    @staticmethod
    def get_custom_attributes() -> Tuple[str, int]:
        # left out for brevity
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def debug(text: Any) -> None:
        """Debug log"""
        logger.debug(text)

    @staticmethod
    def error(text: Any) -> None:
        """Error log"""
        ex1, ex2 = EventLogger.get_custom_attributes()
        logger.error("%s %s", text, f" ({ex1}:{ex2})")

    @staticmethod
    def warning(text: Any) -> None:
        """Warning log"""
        ex1, ex2 = EventLogger.get_custom_attributes()
        logger.warning("%s %s", text, f" ({ex1}:{ex2})")

    @staticmethod
    def info(text: Any) -> None:
        logger.info(text)
```

I'm not sure why I'm seeing duplicate logs when I start my flask application that's being served by waitress.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on (and the question is old) but looks like waitress calls `basicConfig()` for root logger and that somehow causes double logging.
`basicConfig()` does nothing if logger already has a handler, so I did this:

```py
    noop = logging.NullHandler()
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(noop)
```

before setting up waitress logger - and it helped! Now, however, I don't get any logs from waitress at all but I consider it fine, double logging is too annoying.